# Mongoose add element to a document field that is an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a project and have encountered a problem:

I have a document added by user input, and within this document, there is an array field which contains [ProjectID & SubjectIDinProject].

```
"ID": "0001",
"ProjectsEnrolled":[
{
    "ProjectID": "BB",
    "SubjectIDinProject": "BB01"        
},

{
    "ProjectID": "AA",
    "SubjectIDinProject": "AA02"
}
]
```

I have a database with two collections (1.ProjectList, 2.SubjectList). When the user add a new subject into the SubjectList, the ProjectList should update at the same time. Like this:

```
[
{
"ProjectID": "AA",
"SubjectsID":["AA01","AA02"] //originally this array only has AA01
},


{
"ProjectID": "BB",
"SubjectsID":["BB01"]//if the array is empty, should insert
}
```

So I created two arrays from the user input, one containing ProjectID, and one SubjectsID, and pass these two arrays into the following function:

```
module.exports.addSubject = function(id, subject, options){
for (var num in id)
    {
        var query = {ProjectID:id[num]};
        var update = {$addToSet: {SubjectsID: subject[num]}};
        var options = {upsert:true};
        Project.updateAsync(query, update, options);
        //Project is the model created using mongoose
    }
}
```

However, this gives me error "cannot apply $addToSet to a non-array field", and when I change the line to

```
  var update = {$addToSet: {$SubjectsID: subject[num]}};
```

the error no longer shows up, but subjectIDs still aren't added.
Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the **$push** is the most appropriate here,
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: pls show your model design for project and subject